# Куда ставится ударение в "теорема Фалеса"?

Tags: орфоэпия, ономастика

Если имя математика ФалЕс (ударение на "е"), то будет теорема ФалЕса?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

[Фале́с](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) — древнегреческий философ и математик из Милета.
Правильно: **теорема** (кого? Р. п.) **Фале́са**.
[Склонение имён и отчеств](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?fio=on&fio_word=%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81)

Сравните: Корте́с — Корте́са; Ахилле́с — Ахилле́са.

Answer (score 2):

**Если имя математика ФалЕс (ударение на "е"), то будет теорема ФалЕса?**

Да.

Comment: В своём ответе я только хотел подтвердить правильность логики решения, предложенного автором вопроса. В других ответах такого подтверждения нет. Авторитетных источников по правилам постановки ударения при склонении древнегреческих имён я не нашёл ни в сети, ни в других ответах. Я не возражаю, если мой ответ будет удалён, но пока мне нечем его дополнить. В случае удаления моего ответа просьба преобразовать его в комментарий к вопросу.